# Play framework 1.2.5 - Trying to post a Person object to a controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, controller, playframework-1.x

I probably miss something because I havent fully understood some basics. 
In my controller I have something similar to

```
functiona(Person person){
System.out.println(p.firstName);
}
```

The view has the following

```
$.post("/validatePerson",{person: [{name:"first",value:"last"}]},function(result){
alert('done');
}
```

It looks as if the information is passing but the member isn't populated.
I have also tried adding the following typebinder

```
@Global
public class PersonJsonObjectBinder implements TypeBinder<Person> {     
    @Override     
    public Person bind(String name, 
                        Annotation[] annotations, 
                        String value, Class actualClass, 
                        Type genericType) throws Exception 
                        {                               
                        return new Gson().fromJson(value, Person.class);
                        }
                    //return new JsonParser().parse(value) ;}
}
```

Your help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Are you sure person should be an array? It should be an object I think: `{person: {name:"first",value:"last"}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind directly into the controller argument you need to pass in the Person data as part of the request uri.

```
$.post("/validatePerson?person.firstname=john&person.lastname=doe",function(result){
alert('done');
```

}

See how the parameter person.firstname matches the argument name person and the property.

In order to to bind from Json you could get the body as a json element and use GSON builder to deserialise. Something like the following

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(body);
Person person = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonElement,Person.class)
```

Again the json propety would need to match the Person class's properties e.g

```
{person: [{firstname:"john",lastname:"doe"}]}
```